# Average value depending on cumulative value from other column aka running total

Tags: sql-server

I've sifted through the various sql-server tagged threads using AVERAGE and Cumulative as search terms.  Various desperate answers, but I can't cobble them together for my needs. The use case is to find the initial average value (cumulative value/cumulative days on) for a time period when cumulative days on is greater than 60 and less than 90.

Below is a table where ID identifies the object, VALUE is the amount reported on a monthly basis and DAYSON is the number of days in that month where the object ran to produce the value.  YEARMONTH is date value on which on can sort.

```
ID  VALUE   DASYON  YEARMONTH
1    166      27    201502
1      1       2    201505
1    569      19    201507
1    312      19    201508
2    364      27    201502
2    328      31    201503
2    242      29    201504
2    273      31    201505
2    174      30    201506
2    188      25    201507
2    203      25    201508
3    474      28    201502
3    521      31    201503
3    465      30    201504
3    473      31    201505
3    434      30    201506
3    404      31    201507
```

I would like to create a summary table that averages the cumulative value divided by the cumulative days uniquely for each ID where cumulative days is greater than 60 and less than 90.  Below is a table that with the cumulative values. (I generated this in Excel)

```
ID  VALUE   cumValue    DASYON  cumDaysOn   YEARMONTH
1    166      166         27       27        201502
1      1      167          2       29        201505
1    569      736         19       48        201507
1    312     1048         19       67        201508
2    364      364         27       27        201502
2    328      692         31       58        201503
2    242      934         29       87        201504
2    273     1207         31      118        201505
2    174     1381         30      148        201506
2    188     1569         25      173        201507
2    203     1772         25      198        201508
3    474      474         28       28        201502
3    521      505         31       59        201503
3    465      535         30       89        201504
3    473      566         31      120        201505
3    434      596         30      150        201506
3    404      627         31      181        201507
```

I try this based on other threads:

```
    SELECT 
       ID, 
       Value, 
       SUM(Value) OVER (ORDER BY ID, YearMonth) [cumValue], 
       DaysOn, 
       SUM (DaysOn) OVER (Order by ID, YearMonth) as cumDaysOn, 
       YearMonth
    FROM table

WHERE DAYSON > 0 and Liquid > 0 and YearMonth > 201501
GROUP BY ID, YearMonth, Value, DaysOn
ORDER BY ID, yearmonth
```

I can't get it to iterate over the ID; it just keeps summing down the column. If I could create a table or view like the one above, then I could always use a select statement  and divide cumvalue by cumdayson.

Below is a table to show where I would get the initial average value (InititalAverageValue) based on the criteria:

```
ID  VALUE   cumValue    DASYON  cumDaysOn   YEARMONTH   InitalAvgValue
1    166      166         27       27        201502
1      1      167          2       29        201505
1    569      736         19       48        201507
1    312     1048         19       67        201508           55
2    364      364         27       27        201502
2    328      692         31       58        201503
2    242      934         29       87        201504           32
2    273     1207         31      118        201505
2    174     1381         30      148        201506
2    188     1569         25      173        201507
2    203     1772         25      198        201508
3    474      474         28       28        201502
3    521      505         31       59        201503
3    465      535         30       89        201504           18
3    473      566         31      120        201505
3    434      596         30      150        201506
3    404      627         31      181        201507
```

Ultimately what I desire is table as such:

```
ID   InitalAvgValue 
1        55 
2        32 
3        18
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your results don't match your description of the requirements.  You said you want the average of `cumValue / cumDaysOn`, but it looks like your final results are based on `cumValue / DAYSON` (e.g., 1048 / 67 = 16, not 55).

Answer (score 0):

The crux is that you need a running total.  There are several approaches to calculating running totals, but they have various tradeoffs between simplicity and performance.  The "best" approach depends on the expected size of your data set and whether you are using SQL Server 2012 or an earlier version.  The following article describes some different options along with the pros and cons:

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Here's a quick example using correlated subqueries, which may be reasonable for small data sets, but likely would not scale well to larger data:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(CumulativeValue AS FLOAT) / CAST(CumulativeDaysOn AS FLOAT)), 1) AS Average
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            Value,
            DaysOn,
            (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM ExampleTable t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.YearMonth <= t1.YearMonth) AS CumulativeValue,
            (SELECT SUM(DaysOn) FROM ExampleTable t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.YearMonth <= t1.YearMonth) AS CumulativeDaysOn
        FROM
            ExampleTable t1
    ) AS ExampleWithTotals
WHERE
    CumulativeDaysOn > 60 AND CumulativeDaysOn < 90
GROUP BY
    ID
ORDER BY
    ID
;
```

Output:

```
ID  Average
1   15.6
2   10.7
3   16.4
```

Comment: cbranch was correct in they SQL he provided. On over a million rows it took a little over a 100 seconds for the query to run

Comment: In the SQL example I provided, the focus was on providing a working example while keeping it simple.  For better performance, consider some of the alternatives discussed in the article I linked.  Specifically, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, look at the enhancements to the `OVER` clause (great performance, and still pretty simple).  Otherwise, consider using cursors (good performance, but will make your code more complex).